# Is it bad using linear/relative layouts inside a constraint layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I read something about layout nesting which some say is a bad practice but i have a xml layout where it makes me easier to group views with a linear layout and then constraint them too each other.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearMarkStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/linearEndMark">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mark_start"
                android:text="@string/start_label"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:labelFor="@+id/starttext"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="31dip"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/starttext"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dip"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearEndMark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/linearMarkStart">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mark_end"
                android:text="@string/end_label"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:labelFor="@+id/endtext"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="31dip" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/endtext"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

What i have as output now by using 2 linearlayouts as childlayouts in constraintlayout and how i can achieve the same without those 2 linearlayouts because layout nesting is bad so it seems? 
[image]

Comment: What is your question? Nesting is bad, try to avoid too many levels - that's the common sense, there are a lot of tools to profile layout performance, so you can check each case.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin but for my case, to group views can i use a linearlayout inside a constraint?

Comment: According to what you mentioned, one of the roots is useless. You don't need both.

Comment: @GamericiousBlog show full layout file, so that would be clear, currently it's not - what is linearEndMark ?

Comment: @ViktorYakunin another linearlayout which also contains a textview and edittext.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin what i want to know if it can worsen performance if i have 2 linearlayouts as child layouts which i use to group the views textview and edittext and then position those 2 linearlayouts with constraints so i  still dont understand why layout nesting is bad.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin i edited my post.

Comment: Nesting is bad, to understand why you need to know how layout works, it tries to get size of each view, so to get size of linear layout system tries to get required sizes of two child views, after that it tries to get actual sizes of views basing on parents size. More nesting - more passes for layout. ConstraintLayout was designed to solve this problem - one level, easier to compose different views inside the parent.

Comment: In your case - you use linear layouts because you don't understand how it should be done in one constraint.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin so you're saying i should remove those  2 linearlayouts and use constraints on each view separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For performance nested components/containers are better, but in some complex layouts they can make the code easy to understand and help to encapsulate code parts in separate reusable files.

Comment: So for my situation it's okay to have a constraintlayout with 2 linearlayouts as childlayouts to group views? which makes it easier to position i thought but some say layout nesting is bad ?

Comment: Your solution is acceptable, you can use it and don't will have problems, it's only a little bad in performance terms, but in modern smartphones it has not a big impact for the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

As others have written above, nested containers degrade performance, but that doesn't mean that using them inside ConstraintLayout is bad practice. Of course, it is better to use the tools that ConstraintLayout provides, but you don't have to. And the official documentation makes no such requirement.

It depends on what you want to use the containers inside ConstraintLayout for. If it makes your code easier to understand and the nesting isn't very deep, why not?

Answer (score 0):

The "nested layouts is bad" was said in relation to deep nesting. Look at your typical modern web page you will find 10-20 layer deep nesting. If you took that style of layout to Views it will hurt performance. If you are 4-5 layers deep. It is probably fine in all but the most demanding needs.

There is a very small overhead associated with each layer but that overhead grows on the order of 2^n for n layers. So at 4-5 it is 16x to 32x but at 10-20 it is 1024x to 1048576x.

Even a very small overhead becomes a problem when you need to do it a million times.

I am simplifying for illustration (It is a lot more complex)